# In GCP, I am getting billing in Stack Driver Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I haven't changed the retention period of _Default and _Required even though I am getting billing for this.

I have checked in the metrics browser global - Log Bytes ingested resources are:

> bigquery_dataset, bigquery_dts_config, bigquery_project, bigquery_resource, build, cloud_composer_environment, cloud_dataproc_cluster, cloud_dataproc_job, cloud_function, cloud_run_revision, cloudsql_database, gce_instance, gce_instance_group, gce_target_pool, gce_bucket, gke_nodepool, http_load_balancer, k8s_cluster, k8s_container, k8s_node, k8s_pod, ml_job, uptime_url

Can anyone help me to trace why billing is coming? Thanks

Comment: Google Cloud charges for logging. If you export your billing information to BigQuery, you  can query for more information by line item. If you do not want logging, disable it. Go to "APIs & Services" -> "Library". In the search bar enter "stackdriver". For each major feature there is an API. Select those that you do not want and disable. Note: I do not recommend disabling these APIs. Extremely useful for finding and fixing problems. A lot of functionality to log, monitor and measure will no longer work.

Comment: GKE pods application logs like STDOUT and STDERR logs stored in _Default container, right. And its retention period is default 30 days. So, is it chargeable or not? It there is any limit can you please tell or share documentation. Thanks

Comment: Google does not store logs long term in containers. They are stored in Stackdriver (renamed to Operations Logging). Google charges for logging.

Answer (score 1):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) explains in the comments, Google Cloud Platform charges for logging.

In order to disable logging, you have to:

1. Go to **APIs & Services** > **Library**
2. In the search bar, enter `Stackdriver`
3. Disable the API

*NOTE: Is it not recomended to disable the Logging API since it's useful for troubleshoot further problems that you may face in the future.*